# Low-wing taildraggers pictured on 2021 ASA FAR/AIM cover?

Tags: aircraft-identification

There are a pair of low-wing taildraggers on the cover of the 2021 FAR/AIM published by ASA. Can anyone identify them?

I tracked down the image source here, but the description does not identify the planes:

https://www.istockphoto.com/photo/motor-aircraft-on-the-ground-gm1131409963-299576828

[image]

Zwei farbige Motorflugzeuge Sportflugzeuge stehen am Boden auf dem Rollfeld eines Flugplatzes.

Translated to English:

Two colored motorized aircraft, sport aircraft, are standing on the ground on the tarmac of an airfield

Does anyone know what they are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those airplanes are Jodel1050 Ambassadeur. The red one is D-EHKA. The picture has been taken at EDHS, a former military airfield built by the Luftwaffe in WW2.
D-EHKA is based in EDXR (northern Germany)
It has been built in 1964 in France and still flies 100-150 hours every year.
Very efficient, o200A, 5 Gal/h and 100 kts cruise. Can fly up to 6 hours.
Best regards,
Christian
(no idea how this picture made it on the ASA FAR AIM :-)

Answer (score 7):

They are [Jodels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodel#:%7E:text=Jodel%20aircraft%20are%20all%2Dwood,only%20on%20the%20outer%20third.). All wood.  The D-11 was a very popular homebuilt once upon a time (a friend owns one), along with factory production of various models in France in the '60s.  Hard to say exactly which models those are.

Comment: Thanks, @John K!

Comment: Are you sure? They look a LOT like Robin DR.221s...